# The next palindrome smaller than k using c

Tags: c, palindrome

The Next Palindrome

A positive integer is called a palindrome if its representation in the decimal system is the same when read from left to right and from right to left. For a given positive integer K, write the value of the smallest palindrome larger than K to output.

Input

The first line contains an integer, which corresponds to K. Assume that K is less than 200000.

Output

Output consists of a single integer, which corresponds to the smallest palindrome larger than K.

Sample Input 1:

808

Sample Output 1:

818

Sample Input 2:

2133

Sample Output 2:

2222.
below is my program, but i am not able to get the output. please tell me where am i going wrong.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int palindrome(int n)
{
int t,r;
  t=n;
  while(t!=0)
  {
  r=r*10;
  r=r+(t%10);
  t=t/10;
  }
  if(r==n)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
int k,d=0,i;
  scanf("%d",&k);
  for(i=k+1;i<=200;i++){
    d=palindrome(i);
    if(d==1)
      break;
  }
  printf("%d",i);
      return 0;
}
```

Comment: try 898.. There is an even a more severe test case. But I won't give the hint(Find test cases yourself).

Comment: Common homework question with plenty of solutions on this site just convert to s string

Comment: you are using `r` uninitialized.

Comment: initialize variables before using them. you need to learn tracing behavior of a program. this problem is quite common among beginners in c. good luck

Answer (score 2):

I fixed the indentation, init r with 0 in func palindrome, and fixed the loop that checks for palindromes, it now loop forever (while(1)) until it exists (break) when finding a palindrome.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int palindrome(int n)
{
  int t,r = 0;
  t=n;
  while(t!=0)
  {
    r=r*10;
    r=r+(t%10);
    t=t/10;
  }
  if(r==n)
    return 1;
  else
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  int k,d=0,i;
  scanf("%d",&k);
  i = k + 1;
  while(1)
  {
    d=palindrome(i);
    //printf("%d ", i);
    if(d==1)
      break;
    i++;
  }
  printf("%d",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Give output 808 in your program and check the output . When palindromes are given input in this program it returns the number itself .

Comment: You are right, just change the init of i to i = k+1;